# Почему не работают импортированные шрифты css/html?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Не могу понять, почему при открытии html страницы с моего ПК (на котором написан код) импортированные шрифты работают, но при открытии на любом другом устройстве нет.

Может дело в пути к шрифту?
`D:\project` - путь к проекту
Иерархия:

```
project
| assets
  | css
    | style.css
  | fonts
    | montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff2
    | montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff
    | montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2
    | montserrat-regular-webfont.woff
| index.html
```

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../fonts/montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff2") format('woff2')
    url("../fonts/montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff") format('woff');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2") format('woff2')
    url("../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff") format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. А что браузер в консоли пишет? 2. А если открывать как сайт, а не как файл?

Comment: @Qwertiy в консоли пишет `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://hnmpcagpplmpfojmgmnngilcnanddlhb/browser-polyfill.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

Comment: @Qwertiy открывать как сайт не очень понял как

Comment: может, у тебя шрифты и не подключились? Из-за опечатки где-нибудь в названии, например. А на сайте ты видишь один из установленных на компьютере. Попробуй подключи какой-нибудь левый шрифт и проверь на нем. Или попробуй переименуй файлы со шрифтами, чтобы без пробелов, без тире и прочее

Comment: @VladykoD убрал тире из названий шрифтов, ничего не изменилось. Может ли быть проблема в том, что сайт на Github Pages хоститься?

Comment: @VladykoD поставил другой шрифт, которого точно нет на моем ПК, кроме папки с проектом, залил на гитхаб и с ним работает

Comment: @VladykoD у нового формат ttf, может, просто, все это время нужен был ttf, а не woff?

Comment: Нет, не помогло

Comment: между url не хватает запятой `src: url(), url();` woff - woff2 лучше использовать чем ttf

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать, теперь все работает.

Изначально в css файле шрифты импортировались с одним названием и сразу несколько форматов

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../fonts/montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff2") format('woff2')
    url("../fonts/montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff") format('woff');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    src: url("../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2") format('woff2')
    url("../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff") format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Изменил у каждого названия и импортирую теперь только по 1 типу

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MontserratSemiBold";
    src: url("../fonts/MontserratSemiBold.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "MontserratRegular";
    src: url("../fonts/MontserratRegular.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: проверь все браузеры, а также винду и макось. Где-то ttf может отвалиться